# SimpleRetryPolicy: What does the boolean in the Throwable map indicate?

Tags: spring, spring-retry

The constructor for the `SimpleRetryPolicy` allows you to specify which exceptions are retryable. Great!

However, this input is a map where the key is the class of the Throwable, and the value is a boolean. There isn't any documentation on what this boolean value is used for- does anyone here know?

Essentially, it populates an instance of a `SubclassClassifier` whose documentation is too difficult for my simple mind to understand:

> A Classifier for a parameterised object type based on a map. Classifies objects according to their inheritance relation with the supplied type map. If the object to be classified is one of the keys of the provided map, or is a subclass of one of the keys, then the map entry value for that key is returned. Otherwise returns the default value which is null by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `SimpleRetryPolicy.retryForException()`:

```
/**
 * Delegates to an exception classifier.
 *
 * @param ex
 * @return true if this exception or its ancestors have been registered as
 * retryable.
 */
private boolean retryForException(Throwable ex) {
    return retryableClassifier.classify(ex);
}
```

i.e. if the throwable is classified (is in the map), the boolean value of that map entry is returned.

This allows you to set up a set of exceptions where you explicitly state that you **don't** want to retry some exception.

Consider exception `Bar` extends `Foo` (and `Bar` has some sibling classes, say `Baz`, `Qux`).

If you add `Foo:true` to the map and `Bar:false` then `Foo` and all its subclasses except `Bar` are retryable.

Comment: You started your answer with "See", did you intend to list the class that this javadoc came from?

Comment: After some googling, I think you intended to reference the SimpleRetryTemplate source code:

[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.java#L104](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.java#L104)

Comment: I didn't intend to but have now :)

Comment: With the example you provide, is it correct to say that `Baz` and `Qux` are *not* retryable in addition to `Foo`?

Comment: If `Baz` and `Qux` are also subclasses of `Foo` and not explicitly in the map then, yes, they **are** retryable because they are subclasses of (retryable) `Foo`. If the throwable is **not** in the map the classifier checks to see if any superclass of the throwable is in the map (in this case `Foo`). So this example: All `Foo`s (and subclasses, except `Bar`) are retryable. Classes not in the map (i.e. not subclasses of `Foo` in this case) are **not** retryable. If you want all classes, except `Bar` to be retryble add `Exception:true`.